# Support for ICE40UP5K-SG48I in IceStorm?

Tags: yosys

I hope this is the correct place for IceStorm questions ..

The IceStorm website shows support for,

iCE40-UP5K-**UWG30**

The Single Wire Aggregation Demo / Development Board  from Lattice
uses a Different part (package diff only?),

ICE40UP5K-**SG48I**

Will IceStorm work with this part given appropriate  changes to pin
constraints?

I'm rusty at FPGA's .. haven't done then for years ..

So far,

- I looked for projects using IceStorm with the UP-5k
  and found none.
- I checked the ICEStorm site and found

> Support for all package variants of LP1K, LP4K, LP8K and HX1K, HX4K, and HX8K.

The 5K is sadly missing .. This might be the answer to my question
but I wasn't sure if the was dated.

- So I installed **nextpr** and ran,

> ./nextpnr-ice40 --up5k --package sg48

yielding,

> Info: Program finished normally.

Which implies that the ICE40UP5K-SG48I
will work ..

- Then for fun I ran,

> locate -i sg48

to hopefully find more information and got,

> icestorm/icefuzz/pinloc/pinloc-u4k-sg48.sh

So, does this imply it's only for the u4k and not for the u5k .. ?

Now I'm even more confused ..

I'm hoping to get an answer to the question
to save myself a week which might end in a dry hole ..

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Well, after more searching I eventually
found that the IceBreaker Mini uses the
SG48 package and another site that said
it's supported by IceStorm ..